# What is the difference between the _tkinter and tkinter modules?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am also trying to understand how to use Tkinter so could you please explain the basics?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_gui_programming

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between the _tkinter and tkinter modules?

**_tkinter** is a C-based module that exposes an embedded tcl/tk interpreter. When you import it, and only it, you get access to this interpreter but you do not get access to any of the tkinter classes. This module is not designed to be imported by python scripts.

**tkinter** provides python-based classes that use the embedded tcl/tk interpreter. This is the module that defines `Tk`, `Button`, `Text`, etc.